# I am unable to publish app in samsung app store. check the pic for reference

Tags: android, android-studio, publish

I haven't set the android debuggable to true as shown in the picture

[image]

Please check it

Answer (score 0):

In Your build.gradle put `debuggable false`

```
 buildTypes {
    debug {
        debuggable false
    }
    release {
        runProguard false
        debuggable false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
```